# SSH method error

Tags: ssh, ansible

I'm Hi
When attempting to ssh an iLO HPE by Ansible, I receive the following error:

```
[ip] | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1: Name or service not known",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

However, when I ssh [user]@[ip], it looks like the connection is successful.

Comment: That's a DNS error, not SSH. Check your server's DNS record, if it works, check your client's DNS server. Contact your ISP, or change your DNS provider (I suggest `1.1.1.1`) if nesserary.

Comment: Trying to ssh to a local host!private ip to private ip!

Comment: Then how come the error message "Could not resolve hostname" exists? Check your spelling in your connection address.

Comment: `Could not resolve hostname diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` I tihnk you meant to pass `diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` as an option or a value to an option and not as a hostname. You haven't shown us the SSH or Ansible configuration, so nothing we can do to help.

Comment: its my host file
[hosts]
[ip] ansible_user=[user] ansible_password=[pass] ansible_ssh_common_args="diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"

Comment: `ansible_ssh_common_args` should actually be an option to SSH, e.g. `-o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

Comment: By adding options, it didn't work either!